# Python - How to style this line of code?

Tags: python

First of, I'm not sure if SO is the right place for this question, so feel free to move it somewhere more appropriate if necessary.

```
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
```

I have this line of code. The Python PEP 8 document recommends limiting lines to 79 characters to preserve readability on smaller screens.

What is the most elegant way to style this line of code to fit the PEP recommendations?

```
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split
                               (inspect.getfile
                                 ( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
```

Is this the most appropriate way for is there a better one that I have not thought of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am in general with [the answer provided by jdi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12016163/548696) (split into several expressions). But I would like to show another aspect of this issue.

In general, if just trying to properly break and indent this line, you should also follow [PEP8 rules on indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation):

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.
>
> For really old code that you don't want to mess up, you can continue to use 8-space tabs.
>
> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and braces, or using a hanging indent. **When using a hanging indent the following considerations should be applied; there should be no arguments on the first line and further indentation should be used to clearly distinguish itself as a continuation line.**
>
> [several examples follow]

So in your case it could look like this:

```py
#---------------------------------------------------------79th-column-mark--->|
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]))
```

But as I mentioned at the beginning, and as [PEP20 (The Zen of Python)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) mentions:

> Flat is better than nested.
>
> Sparse is better than dense.
>
> Readability counts.

thus you should definitely split your code into few expressions, as jdi notes.

Comment: Thanks! Marked yours as the accepted answer although jdi's is definitely excellent, as yours pointed out the hanging indent bit which i missed when reading the PEP.

Comment: @TerryChia: Thanks. Indeed, [jdi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12016163/548696) is excellent and is really the preferred way (as I pointed out couple times in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the credits towards my answer. I think with a question like this,  you will always have a mix of people that go for pure readibility, or those that claim PEP8. I don't feel PEP8 is the end all be all but some people go as far as to install PEP8 validators on their IDLEs. I guess to each his own.

Answer (score 5):

I would say in the case of your example code, it would be more appropriate to split them up into individual operation, as opposed to making the code harder to read.

```
aFile = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(aFile)[0]))
```

It should not be such a chore to trace the start and close of all those parenthesis to figure out what is happening with each temp variable. Variable names can help with clarity, by naming the intention/type of the results.

If it is two, maybe 3, nested calls I might do the act of newlines in one call, but definitely not when you have a ton of parenthesis, and list indexing squished in between. But normally I am only more inclined to do that with chained calls like `foo.bar().biz().baz()` since it flows left to right.

Always assume some poor random developer will have to read your code tomorrow.

Comment: PEP-8 is against unnecessary spaces in function calls eg. `realpath( os`

Comment: +1 I am fully for switching into several assignments. However, if really necessary for some reason, there is a way to write this line in a pretty clean way in compliance to PEP8 (see my answer). Also jamylak is right about the spaces.

Comment: Spaces gone. I dont know why i even did that here.

Comment: I am with @wberry on the "PEP8 schmep 8" in that answer. Its a proposal and not a law. A guideline for getting everyone to try and stick to standards for common formatting. The most important part is to be readible. If someone can easily see what a line of code is doing, you have done your job. A space inside a function arg list? Bah

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do it like this:

```
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(
    inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]))
```

Open-parens at the end of the first line, and indention on continuation lines.  Ultimately it boils down to what you think is more aesthetic.

There's also no shame in doing part of the computation and saving the result in a variable, like this:

```
f = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(f)[0]))
```

Comment: @jamylak: No, if you refer to the first part of the answer (see [PEP8 entry on indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), especially the "_Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment_" part, and also my answer). Yes, if you refer to the second part of the answer (using additional variable).

Comment: @Tadeck Ah ok I preferred the second answer but I missed that part of PEP-8, thanks for noting that.

Comment: PEP8, shmep-8.  Readable code is code the dude(tte) across the hall can read and understand.

Comment: That is an excellent comment, wberry. I fully support that concept. Its a guideline, not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on keeping it one expression, I'd go with an "extreme" simply because it actually looks nice:

```
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.abspath(
        os.path.split(
            inspect.getfile(
                inspect.currentframe()
        ))[0]
))
```